# subset in data frame to get keep rows less that a given Date in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have an example below where I would like to keep rows (indivisduals) that their cancer date (last column) happened at `10 years or less` (i.e. at most 10 years ) before their inclusion date.

```
d <- structure(list(ind = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `inclusion date0` = structure(c(1414800000,NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               `inclusion date2` = structure(c(NA, 1453075200, 1453075200,NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               `inclusion dat4` = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1544486400), 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
               `inclusion date6` = structure(c(NA,NA, NA, 1594425600, NA), 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"),
               `cancer date` = structure(c(1099267200, 965174400, 1294963200,1458086400, 1230854400), 
                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

d$`inclusion date0` <- as.Date(d$`inclusion date0`)
d$`inclusion date2` <- as.Date(d$`inclusion date2`)
d$`inclusion date2` <- as.Date(d$`inclusion date2`)
d$`inclusion dat4` <- as.Date(d$`inclusion dat4`)
d$`inclusion date6` <- as.Date(d$`inclusion date6`)
d$`cancer date` <- as.Date(d$`cancer date`)
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

Some additional data cleaning

```
d %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(ind, cancer_date, everything()) %>%  
  mutate(across(2:6, ~ as.Date(.x))) %>% 
  gather(-c(ind, cancer_date), key = "inclusion_id", value = "inclusion_date") %>%  
  drop_na() %>%  
  mutate(diff = interval(cancer_date, inclusion_date) %>% 
           as.numeric('years'))
```

Time difference between cancer date and inclusion date is calculated, given in years

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
    ind cancer_date inclusion_id    inclusion_date  diff
  <dbl> <date>      <chr>           <date>         <dbl>
1     1 2004-11-01  inclusion_date0 2014-11-01     10.0 
2     2 2000-08-02  inclusion_date2 2016-01-18     15.5 
3     3 2011-01-14  inclusion_date2 2016-01-18      5.01
4     5 2009-01-02  inclusion_dat4  2018-12-11      9.94
5     4 2016-03-16  inclusion_date6 2020-07-11      4.32
```

Filtering

```
d %>%  
  filter(diff <= 10)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
    ind cancer_date inclusion_id    inclusion_date  diff
  <dbl> <date>      <chr>           <date>         <dbl>
1     1 2004-11-01  inclusion_date0 2014-11-01     10.0 
2     3 2011-01-14  inclusion_date2 2016-01-18      5.01
3     5 2009-01-02  inclusion_dat4  2018-12-11      9.94
4     4 2016-03-16  inclusion_date6 2020-07-11      4.32
```

Comment: thanks. May I ask what across(2:6, ~ as.Date(.x)) does? I want to apply it to my larger data I need to understand 2:6? thanks

Comment: @Lisa to convert the inclusion dates 0-6 to normal date format, though it is not necessary